# R ggplot2 aggregation

Tags: r, ggplot2

HI All I have a data frame with a number of factors, and then a number of numeric fields

The data looks like this

`Date       Source     Device   Sessions 
2014-05-01  Email      Desktop  245
2014-05-01  Facebook   Desktop  132
2014-05-01  (not set)  Desktop  1143
2014-05-01  Email      Mobile   72
2014-05-01  Facebook   Mobile   96
2014-05-02  Email      Desktop  187
2014-05-02  Email      Mobile   32
2014-05-02  Facebook   Desktop  110`

I am wanting to create a line chart in ggplot2 that has the date along the X axis and aggregates the total number of sessions to be represented by the line. I can't seem to find out how to aggregate the data in the sessions columns based on the date value.

I'd also really like to be able to create a chart that uses the device variable to create a line for each value in the column (e.g. a line summing up the sessions for desktop and a line summing up the sessions for mobiles) still using the date as the x axis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Dan: your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
> tt2 = with(ddf, tapply(Sessions, list(Date,Device), sum ))
> data.frame(tt2)
           Desktop Mobile
2014-05-01    1520    168
2014-05-02     297     32
> 
> dd2 = data.frame(tt2)
> 
> dd2
           Desktop Mobile
2014-05-01    1520    168
2014-05-02     297     32
> 
> 
> 
> dd2$date = rownames(dd2)
> dd2
           Desktop Mobile       date
2014-05-01    1520    168 2014-05-01
2014-05-02     297     32 2014-05-02
> 
> 
> 
> dd2m = melt(dd2, id='date')
> 
> dd2m 
        date variable value
1 2014-05-01  Desktop  1520
2 2014-05-02  Desktop   297
3 2014-05-01   Mobile   168
4 2014-05-02   Mobile    32
> 
 ggplot(dd2m, aes(x=date, y=value, group=variable, color=variable))+geom_point()+geom_line()

>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mso it did trigger some thoughts for me that made me think that in order to plot what I want I will need to aggregate my data by date prior to plotting. To this end i suspect your answer while it gets there is a little long winded.

What I went with instead was:
`datedf <- aggregate(sessions ~ date, FUN = sum, data=df);
ggplot(datedf, aes(x=date,y=sessions))+geom_line()+geom_point()`